# Ratio calculation on a group basis in R

Tags: r

I have data like below data;

| PersonId (Uniq) | Disease | Survival |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 2 | B | 0 |
| 3 | A | 0 |
| 4 | C | 1 |
| 5 | B | 0 |
| 6 | D | 1 |
| 7 | C | 0 |
| 8 | A | 1 |
| 9 | D | 0 |
| 10 | D | 1 |

I want to get a ratio from this data table. Calculation of this ratio;

Survival rate by disease: Number of survivors (1) by disease / Total number of people by disease

As a result of this calculation, I want to create a table as follows;

| Disease | Total number of people | Number of Survivors | Oran |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 2 | 0.66 |
| B | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 2 | 1 | 0.5 |
| D | 3 | 2 | 0.66 |

I don't know where to start, what kind of code should I write to get a table like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Disease) %>%
   summarize(Total=n(), Survivors=sum(Survival), Oran=mean(Survival))
```

Output:

```
  Disease Total Survivors  Oran
  <chr>   <int>     <int> <dbl>
1 A           3         2 0.667
2 B           2         0 0    
3 C           2         1 0.5  
4 D           3         2 0.667
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `base R`:

```
tab<-t(rbind(table(df$Disease),
      tapply(df$Survival,df$Disease,sum),
      tapply(df$Survival,df$Disease,mean)))
tab<-as.data.frame(tab)
names(tab)<-c('Frequency','Survived','Ratio')
tab
#   Frequency Survived     Ratio
# A         3        2 0.6666667
# B         2        0 0.0000000
# C         2        1 0.5000000
# D         3        2 0.6666667
```

The dataset:

```
df<-data.frame(Disease=c('A','B','A','C','B','D','C','A','D','D'),
               Survival=c(1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1))
```